# A transversal matroid whose dual is not transversal

Tags: combinatorics, examples-counterexamples, matroids

In Oxley's *Matroid Theory*, Problem 14.8.5, it states that it is (or at least was in 1992) an open problem to determine when the dual matroid of a transversal matroid is also transversal. I had assumed that this did not hold for all transversal matroids, however I've had trouble finding an example of a transversal matroid whose dual is not transversal. Are the known examples of such matroids, and could someone point me towards one?

Comment: I think you'll get an answer much faster on mathoverflow

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try that

Comment: My question was answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271975/a-transversal-matroid-whose-dual-is-not-transversal

Comment: Yeah, one of the comments is mine.